# Найти файлы по списку и сравнить наличие

Tags: c#

Есть список названий файлов в txt (jpg, jpeg, png и т.п.).
Есть папка с файлами картинок на компьютере.

Часть файлов есть, часть файлов нет.

Картинок меньше, чем названий в txt.

Как бы сравнить их так:

1. Взять из txt название
2. Найти в папке файл
3. Если файл есть, то идем в пункт 1, берем следующее название, иначе пункт 4
4. Записываем название файла, которого нет в папке, в другой txt файл
5. и так до конца.

На выходе имеем txt с названиями тех файлов, которых нет физически на компе.

Comment: Слова подобрали удачно. Начинайте писать код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в `c:\temp\list.txt` находится список названий файлов, то пишем

```
var root = @"C:\Temp\";
var res = File.ReadLines(root + "list.txt").Where(file => !File.Exists(root + file));
File.WriteAllLines(root + "result.txt", res);
```

В `result.txt` выводится список файлов, которые указаны в `list.txt`, но их нет в `c:\temp\`

Answer (score 3):

```
var find = //заполняем тем что ищем
var found = //заполняем тем среди чего ищем
```

при помощи `linq` получаем те файлы которых нет в найденных

```
var missing = find.Except(found);
```

`missing` записываем в файл